# VBA Insert blank row based on cell differences

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in this format:
[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRfEE.png)

I want to add a blank row based on differences between values in column B and C.

I have already found a nice piece of code and it works brilliant.

```
Dim i, itotalrows As Integer
Dim strRange As String

itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


Do While i <= itotalrows
    i = i + 1
    strRange = "B" & i
    strRange2 = "B" & i + 1
    If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop
```

But this checks only differences in column B. I have add the same loop for column C, but I ended up with couple of blank rows. The code I made:

```
Dim i, itotalrows As Integer
Dim strRange As String

Dim n, itotalrowsc As Integer
Dim strRangec As String

itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
itotalrowsc = ActiveSheet.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Do While i <= itotalrows
    i = i + 1
    strRange = "B" & i
    strRange2 = "B" & i + 1
    If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

Do While n <= itotalrowsc
    n = n + 1
    strRange = "C" & i
    strRange2 = "C" & i + 1
    If Range(strRangec).Text <> Range(strRangec2).Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop
```

It probably takes into consideration blank rows from the first loop and and another blank row based on that.

How can I tweak the code to have sth like this:

```
If B[i] <> B[i+1] or C[i] <> C[i+1] Then Insert BlankRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, instead of adding a second block, try just adding a `For` loop. (Note I also changed `strRange` to `Range`):

```
Sub t()
Dim i, itotalrows As Integer
Dim strRange As Range, strRange2 As Range
Dim col As Long

itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

For col = 2 To 3
Do While i <= itotalrows
    i = i + 1
    Set strRange = Cells(i, col)
    Set strRange2 = Cells(i + 1, col)
    If strRange.Text <> strRange2.Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' What's itotalrows doing?
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne, but the code you provided doesn't work. It stops after first itteration. It adds one empty row after difference based on 2 different cells in column B and then stops.